# An(GUI) application like lan surfer or advanced ip scanner in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, lan

Is there any (GUI) application like lan surfer or advanced ip scanner in Ubuntu 12.10 to find out shared folders over LAN ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Nmap.

> Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source (license) utility
>   for network discovery and security auditing. Many systems and network
>   administrators also find it useful for tasks such as network
>   inventory, managing service upgrade schedules, and monitoring host or
>   service up-time.<sup>1</sup>

To install Nmap, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Or you can download it [Here](http://nmap.org/download.html)

For a GUI solution, you can use Zenmap.  Zenmap is the official cross-platform GUI for the Nmap Security Scanner.

To install,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install zenmap
```

Or install from the Ubuntu Software Center.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Nmap](http://nmap.org/)</sup>

Comment: I want GUI application which shows the shared folders and host name ..